# How can I get the sum of one column based on year, which is stored in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code.

```
cheese_sums = []

for year in milk_products.groupby(milk_products['Date']):
    total = milk_products[milk_products['Date'] == year]['Cheddar Cheese Production (Thousand Tonnes)'].sum()
    cheese_sums.append(total)
    
print(cheese_sums)
```

I am trying to sum all the Cheddar Cheese Production, which are stored as floats in the milk_products data frame. The Date column is a datetime object that holds only the year, but has 12 values representing each month. As it's written now, I can only print a list of six 0.0's.

Comment: could you include a sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It should be:

```
cheese_sums = []

for year in milk_products['Date']:
    total = milk_products[milk_products['Date'] == year]['Cheddar Cheese Production (Thousand Tonnes)'].sum()
    if total not in cheese_sums:
        cheese_sums.append(total)
    
print(cheese_sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think too complicated.
Try groupby(...).sum()

```
df = milk_products.groupby('Date').sum()
```